# Getting SFDC OAuth login_hint to work

Tags: oauth2

I'm trying to get the login_hint to work when using OAuth, but it seems like SFDC is encoding it during the redirect to the login page in a way that it isn't recognized

Here is my url scrubbed of any sensitive info

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=zzz&client_secret=zzz**&login_hint=username%40salesforce.com**&grant_type=authorization_code&prompt=login+consent&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fendpoint.com%2Foauth2&response_type=code

Which salesforce redirects to

https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DSOME_LONG_HASH**%26login_hint%3Dusername%2540salesforce.com**&sdtd=1

Which doesn't populate the login hint.

If I change the url to

https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DSOME_LONG_HASH**&login_hint=username%40salesforce.com**&sdtd=1

It works as expected.

Is this a bug on the SFDC side, or am I encoding the login_hint incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filing a case with SFDC, it turns out that this is a bug. Here is the known issue  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eQYKAA2.